# Find objects in s3 based on a substring

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, substring

I have a S3 bucket that contains objects in the following format

- 12345-abcde.json
- 56789-abcde.json

If I wanted to retrieve those objects from s3 based on **abcde** how could I do it?

I had a look at the Java SDK documentation and there seems to be no method available to filter based on a substring.

I wanted to avoid to retrieve all the objects from S3 and then filtering them with my own logic if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: You can only filter s3 based on prefix.  Since you want to find objects with different prefixes, you'll have to list all objects with ListObjectsV2 and then filter the results client-side.  When possible, chose s3 object names that align with filtering requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no method to do such thing in SDKs.

But you can do this with aws cli:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/  /my-dir/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*abcde*.json"
```

You can run this command using OS components if you wanna automate this for bulk objects.

For example in python we can run the above command like below:

```py
import subprocess

aws_cli_command = 'aws s3 cp s3://your-bucket-name/ local-directory/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*xyz*"'

try:
    os.system(aws_cli_command)
    print("Download completed successfully.")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```